# Team City deployment failing at OctopusDeploy: Create release step

Tags: .net-core, devops, teamcity, octopus-deploy

I'm trying to deploy a .NET Core app in Team City. The deployment fails at step 4/6: OctopusDeploy: Create release & gives the following error.

[image: Error]

[image: Detailed error message]

> The step failed: Activity failed with error 'The package DevOps.Core.AppService.Placeholder v1.0.0.24 could not be downloaded to the package cache from Octopus Server (built-in) after making 5 attempts over a total of 0s. Make sure the package is pushed to the feed and try the deployment again. For a detailed troubleshooting guide go to [http://g.octopushq.com/TroubleshootMissingPackages'](http://g.octopushq.com/TroubleshootMissingPackages%27).

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to have uploaded the package to OD's package feed. Have a look at step 2/6 - is the nupkg actually being pushed? Can you find it in the OD feed?